# UIWebView Still load the URL even though returning NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am handling a `UIWebView` so that i can control which URLs should be loaded within or not, but some how even though it is retuning the NO , it still load the page. Although documentation clearly says that if you return NO, the `UIWebView` wont load the page.

When i debug,i can see it is returning `NO` but still `UIWebView` does load the URL.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSString *fullURL = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSRange range = [fullURL rangeOfString:@"#"];
    if (range.length != 0) {
        NSLog(@"We need to show the other view");

        return NO;
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, documenting here so it may help someone else. Actually, the HTML, which we were loading using some javascript which was causing this issue. I found out by just using few plain html and testing with them. Once , we know the HTML is issue, we fixed the html and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint or NSLog right before the return YES part. Maybe your method gets called twice for whatever reason, and it returns NO on one, and YES on the other.

Comment: I did and thats why i was telling in original question that i found it is returning NO, its not being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are setting the delegate in viewDidLoad with

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

(take care of not setting it 2 times, in a xib file and in viewDidLoad, it has caused me problems before)

Make sure you implement the UIWebViewDelegate in your class, something like this:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<UIwebViewDelegate>
```

Assuming you have taken care of all this and still you face problems. Also since you debugged and are SURE that the delegate method is returning NO. One reason I can think of as to why this is happening is that you are not loading a new page but using something like AJAX.

I tested the following code on 2 kinds of pages:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSLog(@"THE loadCount is %d", self.loadCount);
    if (self.loadCount > 1){
        return NO;
    }
    self.loadCount++;
    return YES;
}
```

**Case 1:** A webpage where every URL loads a new page. The above code works in this case, and I cannot load any pages after the first load, as required.

**Case 2:** A webpage in which the first load is a complete new web page. But everything else is loaded with AJAX, in that case, my loadCount does not increase and the pages load fine.

That's all I can think of with the data provided. :)

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here, just to extend the answer above be careful when using rails 4 as backend because turbolinks add javascript to every link and then you can get wrong behavior on your delegate, happened to me returning NO on shouldStartLoadWithRequest and still see the request on my server.